# Removed Flash Drive after installation before restarting

Tags: 16.10

I had successfully installed Ubuntu 16.10 on a partition so I could have it along with Windows 10, and once it was over and it asked for me to restart to boot into it, I removed my flash drive thinking I was supposed to remove it. Then errors started popping up saying cannot access this cannot access that, etc., all relating to my Flash drive not being present. So am I screwed? Do I need to reinstall it? Did I screw up by removing my USB before restarting?

Comment: It seems you installed the bootloader into the USB drive, which was a mistake. Please tell us about the computer: Brand name and model. Do you know if it boots in BIOS mode or UEFI mode? This will help us help you. There is an automatic method, Boot Repair according to this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @sudodus I have resolved my problem now, and am now using multiple distros after I became more experienced with partitions and linux. Thanks for the help, and thanks for being willing to help.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad that Ubuntu and other linux distros are working for you now :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest re-install, primarily because 16.10 reached End-of-Life on 20 July 2017.

LTS versions have five years (plus ESM - extended service if you pay), but non-LTS releases have shorter life.  Use 16.04 LTS or 17.04.

Comment: My laptop only works with 16.10, but it says there's no boot device when I boot up. Am I screwed? I have Windows 10 on another partition but still

Comment: *My laptop only works with 16.10* If it works with 16.10, it works with 17.04 and the upcoming 17.10.  Please install a supported release.